# “Free Bitcoins” usless due to high fees

Tags: transaction-fees

Are the various services that give out “free Bitcoins” really giving out air? The amounts are tiny and the transaction fee is way higher due to all the tiny transactions.

Take Bitvisitor as an example. 8 mBTC for viewing an ad is an amount so small that you cannot ever hope to give it on to anyone else while transaction fees in the clients are as *high* as they are now.

Comment: 8 mBTC is .008 BTC, worth over a dollar.  The minimum fee is 0.0005 which is an amount less than a dime.  Did you mean something else?

Comment: I'm guessing he means 8μBTC

Answer (score 1):

Some pages delay the transactions and realize them all in one https://blockchain.info/address/1DFyxn6zpa2wMV1giWPwyG1C4ZacjmWDPw, some pays fees, other don't pay, but it only affects the confirmation time.